# How to calculate core electron SCF Fock Matrix Elements?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I have searched everywhere but there are no worked examples of how to calculate the $\langle\chi_i |\hat{h}| \chi_j \rangle $ values for the Fock Operator using the SCF HF Roothaan method. I am given a wavefunction that is expanded as a set of basis functions, but I don't know how to apply the second derivative to something like

$$
\phi_0(x) = \sum_{\nu=1}^{4} c_{\nu}e^{-kx^2}
$$

Where we assume this is a system with two (spin-1/2, anti-aligned) particles under a harmonic oscillator potential, giving us a total Hamiltonian

$$
\hat{H} = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x_1^2}} + \frac{1}{2}kx_1^2 -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x_2^2}} + \frac{1}{2}kx_2^2
$$

I am capable of calculating the overlap matrix elements for something like this, where I would get a matrix

$$
S = 
\begin{bmatrix}
S_{11} & S_{12} & S_{13} & S_{14}\\
S_{21} & S_{22} & S_{23} & S_{24} \\
S_{31} & S_{32} & S_{33} & S_{34} \\
S_{41} & S_{42} & S_{43} & S_{44}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where each matrix element is

$$
\langle\chi_i|\chi_j\rangle
$$

Unfortunately, I am stuck when it comes to $\hat{H}|\phi_0\rangle$. I am not sure where the $x_1$ and $x_2$ terms come from in the Hamiltonian. I understand that $\phi_0$ represents the orbital that the electrons occupy, but when expanding the wavefunction into the basis set, how do we get the different $x$ terms?

Sorry if none of this makes sense, this is the product of many online learning deficiencies.

Comment: Why is your potential a quadratic?  I think the HF-SCF potential is all coulombic.

Comment: @Bertram This is altered st $V(x_1,x_2)$ is in a Harmonic potential

Comment: Are you trying to calculate elements of the fock matrix for an electronic structure calculation?  The only time I know of when the SCF method is used with a harmonic potential is for vibrational self-consistent problems.